# Advance form - show a field from field group of the channel

Tags: forms

I am new to ExpressionEngine and trying to create an advanced form.

I have displayed the channel and categories associated with it as below as checkboxes:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="books"}
<label for="cat1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat1" name="category[]" value="{category_id}">{category_name}
</label>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

I am now trying to create checkboxes that show a particular field from the channel field group that is associated with the channel, so it adds an extra filter on the search for the user to search.

Can this be achieved or is there a plugin to help with this detailed search criteria?

Comment: Could you post some more info on the fieldtype you want to filter on? What kind of field is it and what are the values?

Comment: The field type in the back end on creating the entry is a multi select.  The values are Book, Speech and Statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little tricky but [Low Search's relationship filters](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#form-tag-relationships) may be able to do what you require. They essentially allow you to limit your search results based on the child or parent entries defined in the search form.

Comment: Sorry I just read your question again and may have misunderstood. Do you want to filter by fields on the current channel or by fields/entries that are related to the current entry via Playa or a relationship field?

Comment: The channel has a field on it that I am trying to filter on.